# Solr search with non-standard ASCII characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

A search which indexes the following string: "Ordoñez" as:

```
text :lastname
```

Is then searched as:

```
User.solr_search do 
  keywords 'Ordonez'
end
```

Will return 0 results.

How can I index the string: Ordoñez using solr and get a match when the search is performed for

`keywords 'Ordonez'` or `keywords 'Ordoñez'`

I have tried the [ASCIIFoldingFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) at index time but this did not do the job.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/097d61cf92627d0c9a83) what I did to try to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the handling on the Container side as well.

You can check [Why don't International Characters Work](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Why_don.27t_International_Characters_Work.3F)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was having these 3 fields, which happen to be unused.

```
<field name="firstname_text" type="textgen" stored="false" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="lastname_text"  type="textgen" stored="false" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="specialty_text" type="textgen" stored="false" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Not too sure why but as soon as removed them, the ASCII filter started working.

The ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory does do the job.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```